# How do I set the style and a style trigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

I am trying to set the style for a WPF content control to a dynamic resource. I can very easily do this:

```
<ContentControl  Style="{DynamicResource RibbonGroup}">
   ...
</ContentControl>
```

If I want to add a style trigger to a content control I can do this:

```
<ContentControl>
  <ContentControl.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowImport}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowImport}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  ...
</ContentControl>
```

If I try to combine these to style the control and have a trigger like this:

```
<ContentControl  Style="{DynamicResource RibbonGroup}">
  <ContentControl.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowImport}" Value="True">
...
```

This XAML creates an error that says the property "Style" is set more than once.

What does the XAML look like to set the style to a dynamic resource and include a style trigger.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 4):

As it says, you set the style twice. Don't do that, use basedon to add to the style you have as a resource.

```
 <ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
           <Style TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource RibbonGroup}">
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I tried this and the result was a runtime error: 

A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'BasedOn' property of type 'Style'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
  Source=PresentationFramework. 
And I am sorry to say that I do not understand what that error means.

Comment: It means i forgot basedon only works with a staticresource.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add two different styles to one singele control yo have to do it in one!

```
<ContentControl>
  <ContentControl.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowImport}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowImport}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  ...
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowImport}" Value="True">
  ...
</ContentControl>
```

However it seems you want to make two styles that share some attributes what you can do in this case is create a BaseStyle and a secund style where you add the BasedOn property like so:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource <X:Key_From_Base_Style>}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was using a DynamicResource. Not sure if StaticResource and DynamicResource are interchangeable here.